# Sorting by recent access in Lucene / Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

In my Solr queries, I want to sort most recently accessed documents to the top ("accessed" meaning opened by user action). No other search criteria has weight for me: of the documents with text matching the query, I want them in order of recent use. I can only think of two ways to do this:

1) Include a 'last accessed' date field in each doc to have Solr sort upon. Trie Date fields can be sorted very quickly, I'm told. The problem of course is keeping the field up to date, which would require storing each document's text so I can delete and re-add any document with an updated 'last accessed' field. Mutable fields would obviate this, but Lucene/Solr still doesn't offer mutable fields.

2) Alternatively, store the mutable 'last accessed' dates and keep them updated in another db. This would require Solr to return the full list of matching documents, which could be upwards of hundreds of thousands of documents. This huge list of document ids would then be matched up against dates in the db and then sorted. It would work OK for uncommon search terms, but not for broad, common search terms.

So the trade off is between 1) index size plus a processing cost every time a document is accessed and 2) big query overhead, especially for unfocused search terms

Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/05/custom-sorting-in-solr-using-external.html

Answer (score 0):

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Solr+Field+Types#SolrFieldTypes-WorkingwithExternalFiles

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/tochildblockjoinquery-in-lucene.html

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: FTA "ExternalFileField is handy for cases where you want to update a particular field in many documents more often than you want to update the rest of the documents."

Comment: "For example, suppose you have some kind of document rank based on number of views. You might want to update the rank of all the documents daily or hourly, while the rest of the contents of the documents might be updated much less frequently.Without ExternalFileField, you would need to update each document just to change the rank. Using ExternalFileField is much more efficient because all document values for a particular field are stored in an external file that can be updated as frequently as you wish."

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can update your answer, I think some explanations around links don't hurt.

Comment: Less >> More. The linked posts are pretty self-explanatory methinks.

Comment: I see. Sorry but those links weren't so clear to me as answer to this question. Have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to understand what I mean.

Comment: So if I put a TrieDate field in an external file, do I just overwrite values in the file directly, or is there some Solr API for updating the values? Would sorting over this external field be slower? When exactly do changes to the file then get reflected in queries?

Comment: ExternalFileField apaprently only supports fields of type pfloat; representing dates as floats doesn't strike me as a great idea, but maybe it would work out.

Comment: You could store date-time as an offset from a base date (say 01-01-2000)

Comment: First link is broken now, second not very useful on its own

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the atomic update functionality.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

This functionality is available as of Solr 4.0. It allows you to update a single field in a document without having to reindex the entire document. I only know about this functionality from the documentation. I have not used it myself, so I can't say how well it works or if there are any pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use option 1, using SOLR queries and updating the lastAccessed field as needed.

Since SOLR 4.0 partial document updates are suported in several falvours: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents

For your application it seems that a simple atomic update would be sufficient.

With respect to performance, this should work very well for large collections and fast document updates.